# Making A listview with JSON Data

Tags: android, json, listview

there I startd devloping in android and i want to get JSON data from a website and make a ListView of all the ID's.
I chacked and i get the jason rawdata from the web but when I try to make it a Json Object i get Lost and after making how I can make my Json Array to ListView On Main UI

XMl

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ScroolView">
    <TextView  //for testing rawData
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/DataText" />
    </ScrollView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ScroolView"
        android:headerDividersEnabled="true" >

        </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>





 package com.example.getjson;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView textView;
    ListView lv;
    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.DataText);         
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Start",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        DownloadData DLD= new DownloadData();
        DLD.execute();


    }

class DownloadData extends AsyncTask<String , Void , String>{
    String Data;
    String [] item;
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... Void) {
            RequestHtml rh= new RequestHtml();
            Data = rh.fatchData();
            item = rh.ftachArray();
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapt = 
                      new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, item); 


        return Data;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute (String text){

        textView.setText(Data);



    }



}


}
```

and here how i get my data from websites

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


public class RequestHtml {

        JSONArray contacts = null;
    String Url="http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/";

    //public ArrayList<Emploee> FatchEmploee(){
    public String fatchData(){
        //ArrayList<Emploee> allEmploeeys = new ArrayList<Emploee>();
        Networkconnection network = new Networkconnection();
        String RawResponse = new String();




            try {
                RawResponse = network.request(Url);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



                return RawResponse;

    }

    public String [] ftachArray(){
        String[] JS= new String []{};
        Networkconnection network = new Networkconnection();
        String RawResponse1 = new String();




            try {
                RawResponse1 = network.request(Url);

                JSONObject jo = new JSONObject (RawResponse1);
                JSONArray contactsArray = jo.getJSONArray("contacts");
                for (int i =0; i<contactsArray.length(); i++){

                    JSONObject jasonid = contactsArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String id = jasonid.getString("id");
                    JS [i] = id; 


                }


            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



        return JS;
    }

}
```

and

```
public class Networkconnection {

    public String request(String Url) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException{

        // make request
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(Url);
        Log.d("Http", "httpGet");
        // make handler to handler the data
        ResponseHandler<String> responsehandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        Log.d("Http", "Hendler");
        //Http client glues together the above
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        Log.d("Http", "httpclient");
        //make the connection
        String response = httpClient.execute(httpGet,responsehandler);
            Log.d("Http", "response" + response );


        return response;
    }



}
```

UPDATE:
Json looks like http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/
Json get parsed correctly Json is right the qustion Is how to export the data from the fatchArray() to MainActivity??

thanks fot the help

Comment: What does the JSON look like?

Comment: http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are getting the JSON response first. Looks like actual response is returning a JSONArray inside a JSONObject. Create a JSONObject first and then do a getJSONArray() on this.

```
JSONObject responseJson = new JSONObject(RawResponse);
JSONArray contactsJsonArray = responseJson.getJSONArray("contacts");
```

Then loop through the contactsJsonArray to get the actual contact JSONObject and parse.

Comment: Wait. Why don't you follow this post entirely (http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/)? Especially doing the HTTP Get part. Looks like you are using this tutorial anyway to get the contacts list.

Comment: I used the Guide for the Jason exemple further more the guide use mainactivity extand ListActivity and I am tring with extnds Activity

Answer (score 0):

Make a class that extends BaseAdapter, and pass it the JSONArray in its constructor. Then override the Adapter's getItem to get the right element from the array, override the getView to inflate some view - simple_list_item1 or similar. Then simply set the adaptr to be the listview's adapter.